# Enum Error while following along a tutorial

Tags: ether

I was going through the tutorial from DappUniversity on Youtube when I stumbled across with my enum

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract HotelRoom {
  address payable public owner; /*state variable, the payment is sent to this address*/
  
  enum Statuses { Vacant, Occupied };
  Statuses currentStatus;
  
  event Occupy(address _occupant, uint _value);
  
  constructor() public {
      owner = msg.sender; /*this is the address of the user who calls this function*/
       currentStatus = Statuses.Vacant;
  }
    
    modifier onlyWhileVacant {
        require(currentStatus == Statuses.Vacant, "Currently occupied.");
        _;
    }
    
    modifier costs (uint _amount) {
        require(msg.value >= _amount, "Not enough Ether provided.")
    }
    
    receive() external payable onlyWhileVacant costs(2 ether) {
        
        currentStatus = Statuses.Occupied; 
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
      emit Occupy(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
    
  
}
```

and the error yields this

```
browser/mycontract14.sol:6:37: ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected enum Statuses { Vacant, Occupied };
                                                                ^
```

Like I said, this is not really my own code, I'm just following along a tutorial. And sorry if my format is messy, I'm new, but ambitious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few small errors your code, but unfortunately the Solidity errors aren't very helpful in this case.

1. After a function or enum declaration you can't use `;`, so your enum should be:

   ```
   enum Statuses { Vacant, Occupied }
   ```
2. You're missing a `;` after the `require` in the `costs` modifier:
3. You're missing a `_;` in the `costs` modifier. If you change it to the following, your code should compile.

   ```
   modifier costs (uint _amount) {
     require(msg.value >= _amount, "Not enough Ether provided.");
     _;
   }
   ```